# Android Fragment Replace

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a screen with multiple fragments and a view pager. I also created a dim function. After 30 seconds the screen dims its brightness and replaces the current fragments with the same image but different colors. My issue is if I am on page two and my dim timer expires. Refreshing the page cases my new fragment to be placed on top of the old.

I am replacing the fragments, the name parameter is not used:

```
    public void replaceContentFragment(Fragment newFragment, String name){
    try {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_fragment_container, newFragment).commit();
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

May layout is as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/PressureMonitorMainActivityBG">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_button_bar"/>
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/circles"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_button_bar"/>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_button_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button android:id="@+id/occupancy_button"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/Room_Mode" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/emergency_button"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_warning"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:drawablePadding="-22dp"
            android:text="@string/Emergency"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have attempted to pop the Back Stack, I have attempted to remove, then re-add the fragments. The newFragment is a newly created fragment. I have been reading that creating a`<fragment/>` in XML makes it impossible to programmatically replace fragments. I do not create any `<fragment/>` objects anywhere in my code base.

Tapping the screen calls the same fragment replace method and the display is corrected.

As requested. In my main activity in `onCreate` I call

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_pressure_monitor_main);
```

My main page displays a label and text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.priceelectronics.pci"
    android:id="@+id/label_and_text_value_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/roomname"
            style="@style/SingleRoomNameStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="46px"
            android:textColor="#CFFFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="@string/Name"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="101px"
            android:paddingLeft="48dp"
            android:paddingRight="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="200dp"
            android:text="0.0000"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="55dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:maxLines="2"
            app:sizeToFit="true"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/variable_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Space
                android:id="@+id/spacer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/label_two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="46px"
                android:textColor="#CFFFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:text="@string/Name"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"/>

            <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                android:id="@+id/value_two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="189px"
                android:paddingLeft="48dp"
                android:paddingRight="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:minWidth="200dp"
                android:text="0.0000"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="55dp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:maxLines="2"
                app:sizeToFit="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My second page displays text and a number

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/label_and_text_value_container">

    <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
        android:id="@+id/roomname"
        style="@style/RoomNameStyle"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingRight="18dp"
            android:textColor="#CFFFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="@string/Name"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value"
            android:layout_below="@+id/label"
            style="@style/PressureMonitorReadingStyle"
            android:textSize="55sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/units"
            android:layout_below="@+id/value"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/value"
            style="@style/PressureMonitorUnitsStyle" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The second page is what remains.

I have attempted to set the text color in order to hide the issue. No such luck.

Comment: Can you add the code where u add your first fragment?

Comment: I solved it by setting the background color of my layout to white. Not sure why this works, but I saw it work for others as well.

Comment: Since the new fragment is added on top of the old fragment and your new fragments bg by default is transparent, it looked like they were getting overlapped. Although what I wanted to see is the fragmentManager you were using to add the first fragment. That might be the root cause of the issue.

Comment: If possible please do add the entire MainActivity's code.